# What should be the architecture of the generator and discriminator model of the GAN for generating 300 * 300 * 3 images?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, generative-adversarial-network

I have usually seen people generating images of 28 * 28 , 64 * 64 etc. For creating this sized image they usually start with the number of filters 512, 256, 128,.. so on in decreasing manner for generators and for discriminators in reverse manner. Usually they keep the same number of layers in discriminator and generators.

My first question is what should be the architecture of discriminator and generator model to create 300 * 300 images.

My second question is ..is it mandatory to have equal number of layers in both the discriminator and generator. What if I have more number of layers in my discriminator than the generator ?

My third question depends upon the second question only, can I use feature extractor part of any famous models like resnet , vgg etc. for making discriminators ?

P.S. if you are writing the architecture code please make it in pytorch or keras .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The architecture of the Generator is completely dependent on the resolution of the image that you desire. If you need to output a higher resolution image, you need to modify the `kernel_size`, `stride`, and `padding` of the `ConvTranspose2d` layers accordingly. See the below example:

```py
# 64 * 64 * 3
# Assuming a latent dimension of 128, you will perform the following sequence to generate a 64*64*3 image.

latent = torch.randn(1, 128, 1, 1)

out = nn.ConvTranspose2d(128, 512, 4, 1)(latent)
out = nn.ConvTranspose2d(512, 256, 4, 2, 1)(out)
out = nn.ConvTranspose2d(256, 128, 4, 2, 1)(out)
out = nn.ConvTranspose2d(128, 64, 4, 2, 1)(out)
out = nn.ConvTranspose2d(64, 3, 4, 2, 1)(out)
print(out.shape) # torch.Size([1, 3, 64, 64])

# Note the values of the kernel_size, stride, and padding.
```

```py
# 284 * 284 * 3
# Assuming the same latent dimension of 128, you will perform the following sequence to generate a 284*284*3 image.

latent = torch.randn(1, 128, 1, 1)

out = nn.ConvTranspose2d(128, 512, 4, 1)(latent)
out = nn.ConvTranspose2d(512, 256, 4, 3, 1)(out)
out = nn.ConvTranspose2d(256, 128, 4, 3, 1)(out)
out = nn.ConvTranspose2d(128, 64, 4, 3, 1)(out)
out = nn.ConvTranspose2d(64, 3, 4, 3, 1)(out)
print(out.shape) # torch.Size([1, 3, 284, 284])

# I have only increased the stride from 2 to 3 and you could see the difference in the output size. You can play with the values to get 300*300*3.
```

If you would like to generate a higher sized output, take a look at progressive GANs.

2. The general idea behind using symmetric layers in both the Generator and the Discriminator is that you want both the networks to be equally powerful. They compete against themselves and learn over time. Having asymmetric layers could cause imbalance while training.
3. Yes. You can use any feature extractor instead of the basic `Conv` and `ConvTranspose` layers. You can use the `ResidualBlock` as part of the encoder and `ResidualBlockUp` as part of the decoder.

Comment: Thank you once again for replying to my queries.....I guess you have worked really well on GANs. Any further suggestions for me regarding GANs. I would really like to follow your sugggestions.

Comment: You're welcome! Hyperparameter tuning is very essential if you want your model to generate quality output. You would be spending more of your time in this process. Some suggestions are to take care of the input normalization and corresponding loss-function, use strided convolutions instead of pooling. Use BatchNorm for all layers except for the input to the discriminator and output of the generator. Though Adam is generally used as the optimizer, I don't think you would go wrong with SGD either. You also need to observe the loss during training since this could give specific information.